# Gulp throws an error when bundling angular and angular-hammer with browserify

Tags: angularjs, gulp, browserify, hammer.js

Gulp throws an unclear error when I am trying to bundle angular and [angular-hammer](http://ryanmullins.github.io/angular-hammer/) (the Ryan Mullins version) with browserify.

For a stripped down version of the app, the package.json file is:

```
{
  "name": "hammer-test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app/main.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "^10.2.1",
    "browserify-shim": "^3.8.7",
    "gulp": "^3.8.11",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.3.15",
    "angular-hammer": "^2.1.10",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

(I included browserify-shim, because an error was thrown asking for this missing dependency for angular-hammer.)

The gulpfile.js contains a bundle task to run browserify:

```
'use strict';

var browserify = require('browserify');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

// Bundle (browserify).
gulp.task('bundle', function() {

    return browserify('./app/js/main.js')
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['bundle']);
```

And finally, the main javascript file `app/js/main.js` contains:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Require stuff.
    var angular = require('angular');
    var Hammer = require('hammerjs');
    require('angular-hammer');

    // Initialize angular application.
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['hmTouchEvents']);

}());
```

The directory structure of the app now looks like this:

```
- app
  - js
    -main.js
- node_modules
  - angular
  - angular-hammer
  - browserify
  - browserify-shim
  - gulp
  - hammerjs
  - vinyl-source-stream
- gulpfile.js
- package.json
```

When I now try to run the bundle task using the command:

```
gulp
```

Then the following error is thrown:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: ENOENT, open '/home/brennerd/Develop/hammer-test/node_modules/angular-hammer/node_modules/angular/angular.js'
```

The error is not very descriptive, but some paths seem to be incorrectly concatenated. Did I make a browserify mistake somewhere? My browserify experience is limited, so that could very well be the case. Or is it not possible to bundle angular-hammer with browserify?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching, learning, and playing around I found the issue. It was indeed a browserify mistake.

Thanks to the documentation of the [angular-hammer-propagating](https://github.com/EpocSquadron/angular-hammer-propagating) fork I figured out that the `package.json` needed some extension. As far as I understand to 1) let browserify know that it should run browserify-shim and 2) to let browserify-shim know where to find the angular-hammer dependencies. The `package.json` now looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "hammer-test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app/main.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "^10.2.1",
    "browserify-shim": "^3.8.7",
    "gulp": "^3.8.11",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.3.15",
    "angular-hammer": "^2.1.10",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "browserify-shim"
    ]
  },
  "browser": {
    "angular-hammer": "./node_modules/angular-hammer/angular.hammer.js"
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "angular-hammer": {
      "exports": "angular.module('hmTouchEvents').name",
      "depends": [
        "./node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.js:Hammer"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

For testing I added a `HammerTestCtrl` with the `handleTap` function to the `main.js` file:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Require both angular and angular-hammer.
    var angular = require('angular');
    require('angular-hammer');

    // Initialize angular application.
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['hmTouchEvents']);

    // Add controller to test hammer.
    app.controller('HammerTestCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

        $scope.handleTap = function() {

            console.log('Tap detected.');
        }    
    }]);

}());
```

I created a basic `index.html` with a square div that calls the `handleTap` function when it is tapped:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test hammer-angular</title>
    <script src="js/bundle.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body ng-controller="HammerTestCtrl">
    <div hm-tap="handleTap" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color: #eeeeec;"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

And in the `gulpfile.js` I added a task to move this `index.html` from the `app` to the `dist` directory:

```
'use strict';

var browserify = require('browserify');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

// Bundle (browserify).
gulp.task('bundle', function() {

    return browserify('./app/js/main.js')
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'));
});

// HTML.
gulp.task('html', function() {

    gulp.src('app/index.html')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['bundle', 'html']);
```

After an `npm install` and this time successful `gulp`, the directory structure looks like this:

```
- app
  - index.html
  - js
    -main.js
- dist
  - index.html
  - js
    - bundle.js
- node_modules
  - angular
  - angular-hammer
  - browserify
  - browserify-shim
  - gulp
  - hammerjs
  - vinyl-source-stream
- gulpfile.js
- package.json
```

After browsing to the `dist/index.html` file it correctly outputs `Tap detected.` to the console every time the light-gray square is tapped. The code for this angular-hammer boilerplate web application can be found [here](https://github.com/basvandenberg/angular-hammer-gulp-browserify-boilerplate).